# Best way to display formatted NSString? Failed on UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, format

What is the best way to display a formatted NSString? I'm trying to format the choices for a multiple choice question on an app.

```
choices1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n Blue \n\n"
            "Yellow \n\n"
            "Red \n\n"
            "Orange \n\n"];
```

I want to display that on the iPhone screen. I tried using UILabel but it doesn't recognize the new line characters. (It prints the words though).

should look like this:

Blue

Yellow

Red

Orange

Thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UILabel defaults to single-line display. If you want multiple lines, set `numberOfLines` to 0, for unlimited lines, or to whatever number of lines you want to cap the label at.

Comment: perfect. thanks very much. as you can see i am a total noob when it comes to displaying texts lol

Answer (score 0):

Change some properties of UILabel like this :

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n Blue \n\n"
                 "Yellow \n\n"
                 "Red \n\n"
                 "Orange \n\n"];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 250)];
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
    myLabel.text = str;
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Enjoy coding..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blue
                                             \n Yellow
                                             \n Red
                                             \n Orange"];
```

Set `numberOfLines = 4` and height of `UILabel = 300`(You can check if string fits in this height. If not increase the height).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spacing your choices with C syntax, you'd be better off to use 4 UILabels and just position the labels on screen exactly where you'd like them. Then you don't have to be concerned with spacing them all apart like that. It's also much easier to modify and see what you're doing when you're designing your interface graphically.